# looper.js plugin - images invisible in between crossfade animations

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate, jquery-cycle, jquery-cycle2

I've been trying to use [looper.js](https://github.com/rygine/looper) to loop through various words or images inside a div ([examples](http://rygine.com/projects/looper.js/docs/#examples-slide-down-cross-fade))

Everything seems to work OK except when I use the crossfade animation option (`class="xfade"`).
**The content appears only during animations, and is otherwise invisible.**

This is fixed by commenting out `position: relative` in `.looper .looper-inner`:

```
.looper .looper-inner {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /*position: relative;*/
  z-index: 2;
}
```

**BUT** it is not an acceptable solution since it messes up my responsive layout on mobile.

*I guess it must be a noob mistake on my part since I'm using default official examples...*

**DEMO:** [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fVf59/)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: A solution has been found on looper's Github page: [github.com/rygine/looper](https://github.com/rygine/looper/issues/11) Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this looper plugin is not very stable, and the support on it is far from excellent. I ended up using this other plugin called [Cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/), which is more popular and highly customisable.

Cycle2 comes with many fancy transitions, but feel free to check out [Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) for other more traditional transitions.

**EDIT**: Concerning looper.js, the solution was to specified the `height` of `.looper .looper-inner` for **every** single animation class you're using (default is 100%).